# Compare two matrices of unequal size

Tags: matlab, logic, comparison, bsxfun, boolean-algebra

I have two matrices A(10,5) and B(30,5). By comparison the final output required is logical array of size (10,30) or (30,10).
My code:

```
A=rand(10,5)
B=rand(30,5)
for i=1:size(A,1)
      X(:,i)=all(bsxfun(@le,A(i,:),B))
end
```

In my code, I am not getting the desired result, in terms of size of output matrix.

Comment: Define "desired result" and how does that differ from what it is now? If you reduce your example (say 6-by-3 or so) you can provide sample input and output, to make it clear to us what you're trying to achieve and where it goes wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
X = all(bsxfun(@le, permute(A, [1 3 2]), permute(B, [3 1 2])), 3);
```

Using the above code, `X(m,n)` will be  `true` iff each entry in `A(m,:)` is less than or equal to the corresponding entry in `B(n,:)`.

Comment: Thanks, can you please explain how permute A, B works together.

Comment: I have an additional but similar question. The minimum Euclidean distance of every row in A w.r.t. all rows in B is to be found. How it can be done using bsxfun and permute. The output will be column vector X (10x1).
X=min(bsxfun(@minus, permute(A, [1 3 2]), permute(B, [3 1 2])).^2, 3).
Please suggest modification.

Comment: @user9003011 I think you are only missing a `sum` over the third dimension to compute the distance; and then minimize over the second. Try `X = min(sum(bsxfun(@minus, permute(A, [1 3 2]), permute(B, [3 1 2])).^2, 3), [], 2)`. Alternatively, you can use `X = min(pdist2(A, B), [], 2).^2`